# A Lucas sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, lucas-numbers

> Define a recursive sequence $\{x_n\}$ as follows
> $$x_0=2,x_1=3,x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}^2+5}{x_{n-2}}(n\ge2).$$ Prove $x_n$ is
> a prime **if and only if** $n=0$ or $n=2^k$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}.$

Note that
\begin{align*} x_n+x_{n-2}=\frac{x_{n-1}^2+x_{n-2}^2+5}{x_{n-2}}=\frac{x_{n-1}^2+x_{n-3}x_{n-1}}{x_{n-2}}=x_{n-1}\cdot \frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-3}}{x_{n-2}}. \end{align*}
Hence
$$\frac{x_{n}+x_{n-2}}{x_{n-1}}=\frac{x_{n-1}+x_{n-3}}{x_{n-2}}=\cdots=\frac{x_2+x_0}{x_1}=3,$$ which implies $$x_n=3x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}.$$
This is a **$2$- order linear recursive sequence** with its characteristic equation $x^2-3x+1=0$. One can easily obtain its general term $$x_n=\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$
How to go on?

Comment: I could be wrong and the question could end up having some weird source, but right now I think this question is question 5/1/33 of the *ongoing* USAMTS competition, see [here](https://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_33_1.pdf) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/there-are-several-questions-here-which-are-basically-from-a-current-2021-202). It goes till 18/10/21. I request everybody to ask for a *source* for contest questions, please, please do it.